# returing data after the call success, ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
'function makeRequest() 
 {
var G_REL_URL="'||owa_util.get_cgi_env('SCRIPT_NAME')||'" 
   var v_data_sales ={ pvCurrCd:"'||CURRDEF||'"
            };       
 $.ajax({
 url:G_REL_URL+ "/contr_entry_pkg.SELECT_SALES_CENTERS",
 data:v_data_sales,
 async:false,        
success: function(vRetVal){
  //var jsonObj =  eval("("+vRetVal+")");
function processresponse(v_data_sales,vRetVal)

               }

               });
          } '||CHR(10)||     
       'function processresponse (v_data_sales,vRetVal){
retJson=eval("("+vRetVal+")");
} ';
```

i want to return a data to a dropdown after there is a onchange='makeRequest"
im not sure if im doing it the right way but is not giving me any errors
and is not working
maybe my logic is wrong but after its success if calls the function
processresponse so it will return  pvcurrcd
but its not doing it.
any help or tips ,thanks

here below is where it make the onchange call which i dont think it matter here

```
 HTP.P('<td class="reqlabel1">Sales Center:</td>');
        HTP.P('<td class="tablelabel">');
         HTP.P(Get_Sc_Dd(PVNAME=>'pnSalesCenterID', PVORAID=> VUSERNAME, 
PVDEFVAL => NSALESCENTERID, PVEVENT=>'class="reqinput1" onChange="makeRequest();" style="width:260px"'));
```

it will change the currency dropdown here

```
    HTP.P('<td class="reqlabel1">Currency:</td>');
        HTP.P('<td class="tablelabel">');
         HTP.P(Get_Currency_Dd(PVNAME=>'pvCurrCd', PVDEFVAL => NULL, 
PVEVENT=>'class="reqinput1" id="pvCurrDd" onblur="makeRequest();"  style="width:200px"'));
```

Comment: [You should probably review the Markdown documentation.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

your code is missing some correct syntax... try this

```
'function makeRequest(){
        var G_REL_URL="'||owa_util.get_cgi_env('SCRIPT_NAME')||'";
        var v_data_sales ={ pvCurrCd:"'||CURRDEF||'"         };       
        $.ajax({
            url:G_REL_URL+ "/contr_entry_pkg.SELECT_SALES_CENTERS",
            data:v_data_sales,
            async:false,        
            success: function(vRetVal){
                //var jsonObj =  eval("("+vRetVal+")");
                            /*
                                fire up the Javascript console in 
                                chrome/firefox/safari
                                and look at the result of:
                            */
                            console.log(vRetVal);
                            // or better:
                            console.dir(vRetVal);

                processresponse(v_data_sales,vRetVal);
            }
        });
        function processresponse(v_data_sales,vRetVal){
            retJson=eval("("+vRetVal+")");
        }
 }';
```